# Who do scripts executed from /etc/init.d/boot.local run as?

Tags: linux, boot

I have some lines appended to /etc/init.d/boot.local on a OpenSuse 11.1 server.  They are some scripts I want run at boot.  Who do these get execute as?  In particular, I have one script that needs elevated privileges, as it binds ports 80 and 443.  On command line, I use `sudo`, but for scripting I'm not sure if I have to include `sudo` in the bool.local file, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All init scripts without code intervention run as the root user.